80's Live action puppet series/movie with a scientist in the basement and alphabet letters or words being stolen
I remember it had to be between 1980 and 1985 in the U.S.A. It was a VHS I would watch with a scientist down in his basement and there were puppets that were helping him solve a mystery. I remember there being lab equipment like beakers and test tubes around and possibly a large blackboard or chart behind him. If I'm not mistaken there was alot of talking to the viewer and breaking the 3rd wall. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have been looking for at least 20 years for this hidden gem from my childhood.

Any chance you're thinking of fraggle rock? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraggle_Rock

No unfortunately not. I'm a big fan of Fraggle Rock. Thank you kindly for trying though, it's been driving me nuts for about 20yrs lol.

Eureeka's Castle maybe?

No, it was much earlier than Eureekas Castle. Between 1980-1985.

Deleted answer indicates it's "readers of the lost alphabet".

Are you thinking of readers of the lost alphabet?


O.M.G YES!! Thank you sooooo much. It wouldn't let me except as awnser but you just made my decade Tami!!!!
